# EC2 GRPC install hangs after 12 hours still no install

Tags: amazon-ec2, grpc

I'm pretty sure it's because I am using `t2.nano` and not something a little more beefy.

But I have used laravel forge to provision an ec2 server, I can't deploy my application however because I need to install `GRPC`.

I have followed these instructions: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#using-pecl

And when I run: `sudo pecl install grpc` it runs for around 10 mins and then just gets stuck.

Seems to be running the same thing over and over again, can't quite workout the full stack trace or more importantly where it begins, but I'll post below.

```
DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"PHP\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.41.0\" -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/channel_connectivity.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/.libs/channel_connectivity.o
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/libtool --mode=compile g++ -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2   -fvisibility=hidden     -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOUR
CE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN     -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES=0     -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1     -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX='"PHP"'     -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX='"1.41.0"' -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.lo
libtool: compile:  g++ -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootRBppUP/grpc-1.41.0/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc -I/usr/include/php/20200930 -I/usr/include/php/20200930/main -I/usr/include/php/20200930/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20200930/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext -I/usr/include/php/20200930/ext/date/lib -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upb-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/php/ext/grpc -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/address_sorting/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/boringssl-with-bazel/src/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/re2 -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/upb -I/tmp/pear/temp/grpc/third_party/xxhash -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM -D_GNU_SOURCE -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -DNOMINMAX -DGRPC_ARES=0 -
DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"PHP\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.41.0\" -c /tmp/pear/temp/grpc/src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/.libs/client_channel.o
```

If there are any logs I can grab please drop the command in to tail or cat and I'll attach them to the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a beefier machine will help since the process takes quite some time.

If the installation doesn't get stuck, **it might look like it's looping through the same command** but that's not the case. At present, the process is slow, and if you have a chance, **leave it running**.

Comment: Yep this was the case, t3.nano has done the trick, annoying because I'd like to run on the cheap. Docker container will likely resolve this.

Will mark correct for future visitors